# Trying to divide two results from sql queries

Tags: php, sql

```
$result="SELECT count(*) as c FROM results";

$result5=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(HomeTeamTries + AwayTeamTries) as ts
FROM results");

$result6=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM($result / $result5) as at FROM results");
```

The first and 5th query give me numbers from a database and these number are 270(1st) and 1110(5th) I want to know how to divide these results to give me an average of the 2 numbers which should be 4.11

I have tries using select sum statements to divide these results but ive had no joy any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the `sum` and `count` terms:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c,
       SUM(HomeTeamTries + AwayTeamTries) AS ts,
       SUM(HomeTeamTries + AwayTeamTries) / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM   results;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain together aggregates in your SQL string you're sending, i.e.

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(HomeTeamTries + AwayTeamTries) AS NUMERIC(10,2))/COUNT(*) FROM results
```

I added in the cast to numeric so that you end up with numeric division instead of int division.

Answer (score 0):

Use divide to get the results

```
select SUM(HomeTeamTries + AwayTeamTries)/count(*) as average FROM results
```